# Calculating Total Count of Items in List<T> for multiple KeyValuePairs in Dictionary<string,List<string>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have a `Dictionary<int,List<string>>`.

I have multiple KeyValuePairs so int the first KeyValuePair the List may have 10 items in it, the second KeyValuePair may have 100 etc.

I need to work out the total count for all items in each list so in my example above I would have a result of 110.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's pretty simple:

```
int sum = dictionary.Sum(x => x.Value.Count);
```

Comment: What if i also want to get the the count in dictionary too... as specified in example... dictionary may have 20 List so i want 110+20=130.. how can i accomplish that?

Comment: @NiravKamani: I don't really understand your example. I think this would be better as a new question.

Comment: I want Perfect query to achieve this"int sum=dictionary.count + dictionary.Sum(x => x.Value.Count);" Ya i will try to put new question..

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a count method which loops through the dictionary and adds the count of internal lists.

Better approach would be to create a specialized collection and maintain this data structure internally. You can override the count method in that class to return count. Then you can optimize by keeping a class level counter and update it while adding and removing items.

Answer (score 0):

This returns your total count:

```
int sum = dictionary.Values.Sum(x => x.Count);
```